# Олимпиадная задачка на рекурсию

Tags: рекурсия, алгоритм

В древнем, ныне забытом языке племени никузяков, обитавших в верховьях рек Большая Турмышка и Пополонь, было интересное правило, позволявшее создавать так называемые красивые слова. Такие слова было принято произносить, приветствуя верховного вождя племени. Понятно, что преимущество получал тот член племени, который произносил оригинальные и, главное, длинные слова. Слово считалось «красивым», если в нём не встречалось более двух согласных и более двух гласных подряд, и «резкие» буквы никогда не стояли на нечётных местах.

Всего в языке никузяков было 9 букв, гласные: а, у, ы; согласные: ш, щ, ф, ж; и две буквы не соответствующие никаким звукам, которые не считалась ни гласными  ни согласными.  При этом буквы ы, щ, ж считались «резкими», в красивых словах такие буквы могли стоять только на чётных местах.

Ваша задача – посчитать, сколько всего разных красивых слов длиной L могли придумать никузяки.

На вход поступает единственное число L - длина слова.

Помогите решить

Comment: @Антон Черепков, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Нет идеи, с какой стороны подойти тут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы тупо не перебрать возможные варианты?

Для уменьшения глубины перебора лучше разбить буквы на классы: *Резкие Гласные*, *Нерезкие Гласные*, *Резкие Согласные*, *Нерезкие Согласные*, *Никакие*.

Исходя из класса последней буквы и длины текущего куска, можно легко установить, какой может быть класс следующей буквы.

---

Вычисление множества позволенных классов по текущему классу и чётности длины слова можно сделать заранее, кстати.

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно. Спасибо.

Comment: @Антон Черепков: Пожалуйста!